# Captcha vk api python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, captcha

Обрабатываю фотки через vk_api, примерно раз в 450-600 фоток выскакивает капча, которую можно пройти заходя вручную на сайт.
Сделал исключение

```py
try:
#код, сохраняющий фотографию

except vk_api.exceptions.Captcha:
     print("Ошибка! Вылезла капча! Пауза 15 секунд")
     time.sleep(15)
```

Спустя пару десятков минут капча, конечно, сама исчезает, но это занимает относительно много времени. Вопрос, как реализовать передачу капчи мне, где я, получая её sid и img, возвращаю запрос обратно к вк
Не смог разобраться в документации vk_api на этот счёт + не понял некоторые ответы на этот вопрос у других людей, поэтому прошу помощи у вас.
Кстати, если убрать except, то вылезет ошибка vk_api.exceptions.Captcha, но я не понимаю как мне из неё взять sid и img

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
try:
#код, сохраняющий фотографию

except vk_api.exceptions.Captcha as captcha:
    captcha.sid # Получение sid
    captcha.get_url() # Получить ссылку на изображение капчи
    captcha.get_image() # Получить изображение капчи (jpg)
```

Смотрите [исходники](https://github.com/python273/vk_api). Конкретно [vk_api/exceptions.py](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/vk_api/exceptions.py).

---

Можно поступить проще. См. https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/captcha_handle.py

Comment: второй способ отлично помог, спасибо!